# Find string in list containing the largest number

Tags: python, string, list

Given a list of string, say `str1= ["State0", "State1", "State2", "State5", "State8"]`.

I need to find the highest State (here "State8"). How can I find it?

Is there a shorter way other than,

```
str1= ["State0", "State1", "State2", "State5", "State8"]
k=0
for n in str1:
    s1 = ''.join(x for x in n if x.isdigit())
    if k<int(s1):
        k=int(s1)
print("State"+str(k))`
```

Output: "State8"

Comment: Is your input always going to be `StateN`?

Comment: Yes !!! The output is always "StateN"

Comment: can't you strip `State` off then and convert to integer? since it doesn't bring anything useful?

Comment: If your output is only ever `StateN` where `0 <= N < 10`, then just sort it as normal...

Comment: @AdamSmith, N<100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function specifying the following `key`:

```
import re
l = ["State0", "State1", "State2", "State5", "State8"]

max(l, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group(0)))
# 'State8'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1= ["State0", "State1", "State2", "State15","State8","State6", "State24", "State7","State11"]
liste = list()
for i in str1:
   liste.append(int(i.replace("State","")))
liste.sort()
print("State"+str(liste.pop()))
```

And this is the other way simple for understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
str1= ["State0", "State1", "State2", "State5", "State8"]

max_1 = sorted(str1, key=lambda x: int(re.findall("\d+$",x)[0]), reverse=True)[0]
min_1 = sorted(str1, key=lambda x: int(re.findall("\d+$",x)[0]), reverse=True)[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `N < 10` in `StateN` then this should be enough

```py
states = ['State0', 'State1', 'State2', 'State5', 'State8']

max(states)
```

Else, this should do the trick

```py
max(int(s.replace('State', '')) for s in states)
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a new list of values containing just the integer parts, get the `max()` of that list, then print it with "State":

```
integers = [int(x[5:]) for x in str1]
print("State%d" % max(integers))
```